# How to connect Motorola MC3190 to PC using Windows 8.1 x64?

Tags: usb, drivers, windows-ce, windows-8-x64

I've been happing using a USB sync cradle to connect to our MC3190 scanners via my old Windows 7 Pro x86 for over a year now.  I recently got a newer, faster PC running Windows 8.1 Pro x64.  When I tried to connect the USB Sync Cradle, it appears in device manager as "Symbol USB Sync Cradle" and although I found a driver for it via Windows Update Catalog that matches the hardware id, it just will not install, displaying the message:

> Windows encountered a problem installing the driver software for your device
>
> Windows found driver software for your device but encountered an error while attempting to install it.
>
> Symbol USB Sync
>
> The system cannot find the file specified.

The "C:\Windows\inf\setupapi.dev.log" log file shows this:

```
>>>  [Device Install (DiShowUpdateDevice) - USB\VID_05E0&PID_2000\5&54C1B55&0&10]
>>>  Section start 2014/10/11 19:38:49.327
      cmd: "C:\Windows\system32\mmc.exe" "C:\Windows\system32\compmgmt.msc" /s
     dvi: {DIF_UPDATEDRIVER_UI} 19:38:49.327
     dvi:      No class installer for 'Symbol USB Sync Cradle'
     dvi:      No CoInstallers found
     dvi:      Default installer: Enter 19:38:49.327
     dvi:      Default installer: Exit
     dvi: {DIF_UPDATEDRIVER_UI - exit(0xe000020e)} 19:38:49.327
     ndv: {Update Driver Software Wizard for USB\VID_05E0&PID_2000\5&54C1B55&0&10}
     ndv:      Driver package 'c:\users\matty\desktop\symbol usb cradle\microsoft corporation - other hardware - symbol usb sync\x64\wceusbsh.inf' exists under 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\wceusbsh.inf_amd64_ed7e79d05f4c4512\wceusbsh.inf'.
     dvi:      Searching for hardware ID(s):
     dvi:           usb\vid_05e0&pid_2000&rev_0000
     dvi:           usb\vid_05e0&pid_2000
     dvi:      Searching for compatible ID(s):
     dvi:           usb\class_ff&subclass_ff&prot_ff
     dvi:           usb\class_ff&subclass_ff
     dvi:           usb\class_ff
     dvi:      {DIF_SELECTDEVICE} 19:39:03.745
     dvi:           No class installer for 'Symbol USB Sync Cradle'
     dvi:           No CoInstallers found
     dvi:      {DIF_SELECTDEVICE - exit(0xe000020e)} 19:39:03.761
     dvi:      {DIF_SELECTDEVICE} 19:39:16.361
     dvi:           No class installer for 'Symbol USB Sync Cradle'
     dvi:      {DIF_SELECTDEVICE - exit(0xe000020e)} 19:39:16.377
     ndv:      Driver package 'c:\users\matty\desktop\symbol usb cradle\microsoft corporation - other hardware - symbol usb sync\x64\wceusbsh.inf' exists under 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\wceusbsh.inf_amd64_ed7e79d05f4c4512\wceusbsh.inf'.
     dvi:      Searching for hardware ID(s):
     dvi:           usb\vid_05e0&pid_2000&rev_0000
     dvi:           usb\vid_05e0&pid_2000
     dvi:      Searching for compatible ID(s):
     dvi:           usb\class_ff&subclass_ff&prot_ff
     dvi:           usb\class_ff&subclass_ff
     dvi:           usb\class_ff
     ndv: {Update Driver Software Wizard exit(00000002)}
<<<  Section end 2014/10/11 19:39:19.327
<<<  [Exit status: FAILURE(0x00000002)]
```

Is there a certain way of doing things to get it working, or another driver I could try?

Is anyone else developing software for the Motorola MC31X0 devices from a Windows 8.1 Pro x64 PC?

Hardware Id: USB\VID_05E0&PID_2000

Scanner part no: MC3190-SI4H04E0A; Cradle part no: CRD3000-1001RR.

Comment: "will not install"... error messages etc would be useful

Comment: I've added the error message to the question.

Comment: Ouch - that's nearly as useful as 'bad command or syntax error' ;-)  Can you find a log file anywhere that may be more informative?

Comment: I've looked at the Windows Event Log "Microsoft-Windows-DeviceSetupManager/Admin", but that doesn't tell me much: Event ID 121, Driver install failed, result=0x80070002 for devnode 'USB\VID_05E0&PID_2000\5&54C1B55&0&10'.

Comment: Sorry, I'm outside my knowledge area, but I wish you luck - I presume you already saw https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Mobile+Networks+RFID+and+BarCode+Scanners/RFID+Products/MC3190-Z_US-EN

Comment: I've raised a support case with Symbol/Motorola.  I'll add the answer to this question, if I get one.  It'll probably be Monday before they respond though.  Thanks for your time though, Tetsujin :).

Comment: Wish you luck, fingers crossed :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correct this issue, I uninstalled Windows Mobile Device Center, right clicked and Uninstalled the USB Sync Cradle in device manager and scanned the PC for new hardware.  This time, when the driver was installed Windows Mobile Device Center was installed at the same time as the driver.

I think my issue was probably caused by me installing things in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

Go into Settings on the handheld and under Connections>US to PC, uncheck the box to Enable Adavanced Network Functionality.  Worked for me at least

Comment: DOnt know who downvoted, this actually worked, but a different config was chosen, USBCONFIG, and then set into MassStorage mode.